# Why do I keep getting TypeError?

Tags: python, init, scapy

This is the error I am getting, but only when I try to run the code using `argparse`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "portscanner.py", line 63, in <module>
    Main()
  File "http://portscanner.py", line 58, in Main
    AN(args.ip_addr)
  File "http://portscanner.py", line 34, in AN
    s = IP(dst=ip_addr)/TCP(sport=80, dport=80, flags="S") # creates packet ("S")
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dst'
```

Code:

```
from logging import getLogger, ERROR
getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(ERROR)
from scapy.all import *
import argparse
import sys
import socket
from IPy import IP

def create_packet(ip_addr):
    s = IP(dst=ip_addr)/TCP(sport=80, dport=80, flags="S") # creates packet ("S")
    print "pass"
def Main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script for port scanning')
    parser.add_argument("-H", "--host", help="host IP", dest="ip_addr", required=True, default="localhost")
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--syn", help="conduct a syn flag scan", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--icmp", help="conduct a ICMP scan", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("-sp", "--start-port", help="starting/main port (s)", dest="dest_port", type=int, action="store")
    parser.add_argument("-ep", "--end-port", help="ending port port (s)", dest="eport", type=int, action="store")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.syn:
        IP(args.ip_addr)
        create_packet(args.ip_addr)
    else:
        print 'fail'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The error happens on like 34 where `scapy` is crafting the packet. Now when the similar code (craft the packet in a different program) I do not get the "dst" error.

```
def scan(port):
    s = IP(dst=ip_addr)/TCP(sport=s_port, dport=port, flags="S") # creates packet ("S")
    snd = sr1(s, timeout=2) # sends packet
    if str(type(snd)) == "<type 'NoneType'>":
        pass
    elif snd.haslayer(TCP): # checks the layer of the response from server
        if snd.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x12:
            r = IP(dst=ip_addr)/TCP(sport=s_port, dport=port, flags="R")
            rsnd = sr(r, timeout=2) # closes the connection
            print '[*] Port %d is open' % port
        elif snd.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x14:
            pass # checks for rst packet
```

I searched Google, and I saw a similar error  that other had, but I could not see why my code is doing this. Especially when it works in a different program.

Comment: Why are you using `dst=` *at all*? The `IPy.IP()` class doesn't have such a keyword parameter.

Comment: Actually, why are you using `IPy` *at all* when you are also using `from scapy import *` here; you are using the `IPy.IP()` class togeher with the `TCP` class from `scapy`, and that won't work *either*.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a `dst=` keyword argument to the `IPy.IP()` class:

```
from IPy import IP

# ...

IP(dst=ip_addr)
```

That class doesn't define such a keyword argument. Looking at the [project documentation](https://github.com/autocracy/python-ipy/) I see no such keyword defined, there is only a *positional* `data` argument [defined in the `__init__` method](https://github.com/autocracy/python-ipy/blob/master/IPy.py#L139):

```
def __init__(self, data, ipversion=0, make_net=0):
```

You could drop the `dst=` part:

```
IP(ip_addr)
```

But perhaps you got confused with the `scapy` `IP()` class instead.

I certainly doubt you can mix the `IPy.IP()` class with the `scapy` `TCP()` class like you try to do in your code. Perhaps you want to *remove* the `from IPy import IP` line altogether instead.